# Weak convergence and norm convergence implies strong convergence in arbitrary $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in a $L^p$ space that converges weakly to $f$. Here $1<p<\infty$.

Also assume that $\| f_n\| _p$ converges to $\| f\| _p$.

Then how do I show that $\| f_n-f\|_p $ goes to $0$? It was easy for $p=2$ but I am stuck at arbitrary cases. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following inequality for $f$ and $g$ in the unit ball of $L^p$
$$
\lVert  f - g \rVert_{p}^{p} \leq C_{p} \left[ \lVert f \rVert_{p}^{p} + \lVert g \rVert_{p}^{p} -2 \left\lVert \frac{f + g}{2} \right\rVert_{p}^{p} \right]^{\min q(p)},
$$
where $q(p)=\min \{1, p/2 \}$,
was shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032366/on-a-clarkson-like-inequality-in-lp).

In our problem, we can assume that $\lVert f_n\rVert_p\leqslant 1$ for all $n$.

Applying the mentioned inequality with $g=f_n$ gives 
$$
\lVert  f -f_n \rVert_{p}^{p/q(p)}\leq C_{p}  \left(\lVert f \rVert_{p}^{p} + \lVert f_n \rVert_{p}^{p} -2 \lVert \frac{f +f_n}{2} \rVert_{p}^{p}\right).
$$
Take the $\limsup_{n\to +\infty}$ and use the assumption and the fact that $h_n=f+f_n\to 2f$ weakly in $L^p$ and 
$$
\lVert h\rVert_p^p\leqslant \liminf_{n\to +\infty}\lVert h_n\rVert_p^p.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much...could you also help me with this one?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572270/weak-convergence-combined-with-a-e-convergence-imply-something

Comment: I tried to use the inequality to the problem in the link but cannot proceed on..